# How to separate string for Letters and Numbers and than setcookie php

Tags: php, pdo, setcookie

I have $_GET query

```
$_GET['code'] = 'AB123'; // example
```

I tried:

```
if(isset($_GET["code"])){

   $codes = $_GET["code"];
   preg_match("/([a-zA-Z]*)([\-0-9]*)/", $codes, $refid);   
   setcookie("code",$refid,time()+2592000);

}
```

Than I checked the result.

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['code'])) {
  $ref_id = $_COOKIE['code'];
}
```

But when i tried to add this value to hidden input i can't get the value.

```
<input type="hidden" name="refid" value="<?=$ref_id;?>">
```

Edited (right) version:

```
if(isset($_GET["code"])){

   $codes = $_GET["code"];
   preg_match("/([a-zA-Z]*)([\-0-9]*)/", $codes, $refid); 
   $refarr = $refid[2];
   setcookie("code",$refarr,time()+2592000);

}
```

Comment: setcookie() expects parameter 2 to be string,

$refid is an array.

Comment: Because your are trying to assign array to cookie. But cookie only accept strings

Comment: OMG Sure. edited questions with the right result.